# DVI-I To HDMI 1.3

Tags: hdmi, dvi, nvidia-graphics-card, adapter

I bought a DVI-I to HDMI adapter for about a buck and it didn't work.
I have an old NVIDIA GeForce 9500 GT with a VGA and DVI-I socket and a few years old TV with HDMI 1.3 .
When I hooked it up nothing happened, and the computer didn't recognize it.
The cable and TV are OK, so maybe I need another adapter, or maybe this one was damaged?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes TVs are dumb, they don't handle the resolution your PC is pumping out. You might have to choose a lower resolution and work your way up the resolution scale to determine the max your TV can handle.

Comment: You see, the thing is that the pc doesn't even recognize the TV. I connected another display and it doesn't detect it. Anything else I can do?